# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x100041038) in XCODE

Tags: c, xcode, memory-management, exc-bad-access

Trying to allocate memory manually from a heap reserve. 1MB of heap space is allocated using:

```
partition = *(partition_t*) malloc(1048576*sizeof(partition_t));
```

where 'partition' is a struct of a single char (1 byte):

```
typedef struct {
char dummy;
}partition_t;
```

Later in the code a struct meta_t, containing meta-data about the partition, is placed in the first 40 bytes of each partition using:

```
boolean start_memory(partition_t *partition_ptr, global_memory_info_t *global_memory_info_ptr)
{
boolean initialized = False;
partition_meta_t meta;

if (partition_ptr != NULL)
{
    global_memory_info_ptr->memory_size = SIZE;
    global_memory_info_ptr->free_memory = SIZE;
    global_memory_info_ptr->used_memory = 0;
    global_memory_info_ptr->block_base_address = partition_ptr;

    meta.size = SIZE;
    meta.available = True;
    meta.start_address = partition_ptr;
    meta.used_memory = 0;
    meta.extra_memory = 0;
    meta.next_partition = NULL;
    meta.prev_partition = NULL;

    *((partition_meta_t *)partition_ptr) = meta;

    initialized = True;  
}   
return initialized;
}
```

The meta-data also serves as a linked-list to keep track of additional partitions.

Binary multiples (2^n) of memory size requests are made by the user and the partition is repeatedly halved until an appropriate chunk is found. The check for appropriate size is done elsewhere. The function below halves the passed partition and affixes meta-data to the starting address of the new partition.

```
void mem_chopper(partition_t *partition_ptr)
{
partition_meta_t meta;

int start_address_offset = ((partition_meta_t *)(partition_ptr))->size / 2 ;

meta.start_address = ((partition_meta_t *)(partition_ptr))->start_address + (((partition_meta_t *)(partition_ptr))->size / 2);
meta.available = True;
meta.size = start_address_offset;
meta.used_memory = 0;
meta.extra_memory = 0;
meta.next_partition = NULL;
meta.prev_partition = NULL;
((partition_meta_t *)(partition_ptr))->next_partition = meta.start_address;
((partition_meta_t *)(partition_ptr))->size = start_address_offset;

meta.prev_partition = ((partition_meta_t *)(partition_ptr))-> start_address;

*((partition_meta_t *)meta.start_address) = meta;

}
```

The problem is: the mem_chopper() function will execute fine the first time and divide the initial partition and place meta-data in the new partition. However, on the second pass to divide the partition again I will get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x100041038).

The address coincides, 0x100041038, with exactly 1/4 of the original 1MB of memory. When I allocate 2MB of heap space, the program still crashed at address 0x100041038, now 1/8 of the allocated memory.

Why is this crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x100041038)?

The entire code is at the following:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ykxan6n9h700wi/Ass5v3.zip?dl=0

Heap size is defined in mem_commands.h by the variable SIZE.

Comment: `partition = *(partition_t*) malloc(1048576*sizeof(partition_t));` is a memory leak.

Comment: @ zenith - Oh? please ellaborate.

Comment: You lose the pointer returned by `malloc`, and therefore cannot free it.

Comment: So later, when I free(partition), that won't work? Even if I have saved the starting address of the partition elsewhere? Is this a cause of the EXC_BAD_ACCESS ?

Comment: You can't free `partition` if it's of type `partition_t` because then it's allocated on the stack. Unless you store the pointer returned by `malloc` somewhere.  "Is this a cause of the EXC_BAD_ACCESS ? " Maybe.

Comment: would this fix it? partition_t* partition = (partition_t*) malloc(SIZE*sizeof(partition_t));

Comment: Yes. But you don't need the cast.

Comment: partition_t* partition = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(partition_t)); Ok, that did stop the BAD_ACCESS. Thank you zenith. It took me longer to write the question than it did for you to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: `partition_t *partition = *(partition_t*) malloc(1048576*sizeof(partition_t));`  the reason is that you are trying to dereference a pointer that is returned by malloc() after type casting it from (void *) to (partition_t *).  So essentially there is a mismatch between pointer type and value assigned to it.  It should have been `partition_t *partition = (partition_t*) malloc(1048576*sizeof(partition_t));`